# Uploading text from file directly in to Database asp.net5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filestream

Right know I get an `IFormFile` to my controller save it in a temp folder and then I use the `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` to get to the text in the file and store that in my database. After that I delete the file again. Is there a way that I can skip the whole saving part and get the text out of the `IFormFile` directly?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(ViewModel model)
    {
        model.file.SaveAsAsync(@"c:\temp\temp.txt");
        String txt= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\temp.txt ");
        db.saveText(txt);
        System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\Temp\temp.txt ");

        return Redirect("/Home");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the related code to get better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using httpPostedFileBase class returns the HttpInputStreamObject as per specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.100).aspx)

You should convert the stream into byte array and then you can read file content

Please refer following link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Zergling the conversion to byte Array helped a lot. From there I converted the content to text with System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(). Happy holidays and KEKEKEKEE

Comment: happy coding , happy holidays aswell